# No protocol specified installing xampp

Tags: xampp

I am a happy owner Ubuntu 17.10. Works fine, a little problem with the flash player on the chrome, but i gave advice. Now I want to install XAMPP and ...

```
    bogdan@bogdan-dom:~/Downloads$ chmod 755 xampp*
    bogdan@bogdan-dom:~/Downloads$ stat xampp*
      File: xampp-linux-x64-7.1.11-0-installer.run
      Size: 140031648   Blocks: 273512     IO Block: 4096   regular file
    Device: 805h/2053d  Inode: 1332894     Links: 1
    Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/  bogdan)   Gid: ( 1000/  bogdan)
    ...
    ...
     Birth: -
    bogdan@bogdan-dom:~/Downloads$ sudo ./xampp*
    [sudo] password for bogdan: 
    No protocol specified
    No protocol specified
    No protocol specified
    No protocol specified
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Welcome to the XAMPP Setup Wizard.

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Select the components you want to install; clear the components you do not want
    to install. Click Next when you are ready to continue.

    XAMPP Core Files [y/N] :
```

after a few Yes...

```
    Please wait while Setup installs XAMPP on your computer.
     Installing
     0% ______________ 50% ______________ 100%
     #########################################
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Setup has finished installing XAMPP on your computer.

    run
    help
    exit
```

I tried anything but the terminal is deaf (can write)

I know that before *No protocol specified* it should show the installer window

Please help

Comment: I managed to resolve this after a long search. Here's how: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YKCW8lAkd8

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I think it's a Wayland issue.
Try logging in with xorg.
Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Newer systems by design don't allow graphical applications as root (it's a Wayland thing). Workaround:

```
xhost si:localuser:root

sudo   your-graphical-app
```

Restore the default permissions:

```
xhost -si:localuser:root
```